# What's wrong with my (attempted) implementation of iterateM?

Tags: haskell, monads

I would like to implement a function, iterateM, whose type would look like this:

```
iterateM :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> [m a]
```

However, my first go at writing this function:

```
iterateM f x = f x >>= (\x' -> return x' : iterateM f x')
```

Gives me the error:

```
Could not deduce (m ~ [])
from the context (Monad m)
  bound by the type signature for
             iterateM :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> [m a]
  at main.hs:3:1-57
  `m' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        iterateM :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> [m a]
      at main.hs:3:1
Expected type: [a]
  Actual type: m a
In the return type of a call of `f'
In the first argument of `(>>=)', namely `f x'
In the expression: f x >>= (\ x' -> return x' : iterateM f x')
```

If I remove my type-signature, ghci tells me the type of my function is:

```
iterateM :: Monad m => (a -> [a]) -> a -> [m a]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try this: `iterateM f = iterate . f` (this probably has nothing to do with monads).

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for, that gives me: (a -> a1 -> a1) -> a -> a1 -> [a1].  I'll try and put together a simple use case for my imaginary function.  The main difference here from iterate, is I want to take the inner value from f's result and push into the next call of the function, much like >>= does.

Comment: I also suspect the type signature you want is (a -> m a) -> a -> m [a], not [m a]

Comment: Would that work, or would the function recurse forever?

Comment: @Adam, depends on `m`.  It would never terminate in `IO`.  There would be no problem with `Reader`.  `Writer` depends on the monoid. In general, it will recurse forever for any monad that is strict in the first argument of `(>>=)`.

Comment: @luqui, Good to know... I've not used Reader/Writer much yet, but I had wondered about their behavior in scenarios like these.

Comment: @Adam sorry, that's what happens when you answer from a mobile phone at 5:30 am... I tried to check the signature with ideone and it didn't complain for some weird reason.

Comment: @n.m. No worries. I always appreaciate any comments/answers I get to these questions of mine.  Whether they solve the problem or not.  If nothing else, they make me think a bit differently about the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I gather from your signature:

```
iterateM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m a) -> a -> [m a]
```

Is that the `n`th element `iterateM f x` will be an action that runs `f` `n` times.  This is very close to `iterate`, I suspect we can implement it in terms of that.

```
iterate :: (b -> b) -> b -> [b]
```

`iterate` gives us a list of `b`s, and we want a list of `m a`s, so I suspect `b = m a`.

```
iterate :: (m a -> m a) -> m a -> [m a]
```

Now we need  a way to transform `f :: a -> m a` into something of type `m a -> m a`.  Fortunately, that is exactly the definition of bind:

```
(=<<) :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> (m a -> m b)
```

So:

```
\f -> iterate (f =<<) :: (a -> m a) -> m a -> [m a]
```

And to get our initial `x :: a` into the desired `m a`, we can use `return`:

```
return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a
```

So:

```
iterateM f x = iterate (f =<<) (return x)
```

Pointfreeize to taste.

Comment: One note, and I think this is just me misunderstanding what I was looking for... this will actually repeat the first action every 'iteration' and then the second action every iteration (except for the first, that is).  That's not exactly the behavior I was expecting, though I understand why it is happening.

Comment: @Adam, that depends on how you use it.  It's just a list of independent actions; which ones you choose to execute and in what order is up to you.

Comment: ahh you're right!  I was using `sequence` when this happened... If I change this to `last` then it works exactly as expected.

Comment: `\f -> iterate (f =<<) :: (a -> m a) -> m a -> m a` should be `\f -> iterate (f =<<) :: (a -> m a) -> m a -> [m a]` right?

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive use of iterateM is forcing it to be in the list monad.  You need to run the iterateM action and return its result.

Try:

```
iterateM f x = do
      x' <- f x
      xs <- iterateM f x'
      return $ x':xs
```

Comment: That will have signature `(a -> m a) -> a -> m [a]`.  May be what the OP is looking for, maybe not.

Comment: I was hoping for [m a], is there a reason why that won't work?

Comment: But that does explain why I was getting a list in the inferred type-signature.

Comment: @luqui +1 woops, I'm without ghci at the moment.

Comment: I believe this would be the same as `sequence $ luquiIterateM f x`